# JavaScript: window.matchMedia() Mobile Browser Support

Tags: javascript, matchmedia

As far as I can tell, with the help of [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=matchmedia), `window.matchMedia` is supported on most popular browsers, with the exception of IE<10 (which are, admittedly not wildly popular these days).

Would any one know whether non-supporting browsers, such as IE<10, have much of a presence on mobile platforms?

This will help me to make a pragmatic decision for a polyfill I am writing. That is, if `matchMedia()` is not supported, then it’s probably a desktop browser, and we can take it from there.

Thanks

Comment: Why would IE<=9 be running on a mobile device?

Comment: @torazaburo That’s what I’m asking. As far as I am aware, they were running on Windows Mobile just a few years ago, and I don’t know about other legacy browsers.